# run java application from jar with properties

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a service where i am running a jar file by passing properties file

```
java -jar myjar server config.yml
```

In order to stop passing `config.yml` every time through command line I have configured below code in my main method :

```
String configFile = args.length > 0
  ? args[0]
  : ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("config.yml").toString();
new myApplication.run("server", configFile);
```

When I run my application with

```
java -jar myjar
```

I am getting the below exception. Please help me understand what's the cause.

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   jar:file:/Users/abc/proj/target/analytics-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/config.yml
>   not found
>           at io.dropwizard.configuration.FileConfigurationSourceProvider.open(FileConfigurationSourceProvider.java:14)

Comment: Check if the file is at the path that is stated in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("config.yml").toString();
```

This will create string representation of resource URL (thats inside JAR). `File` cannot read from because it is not accessible to file system. You should rather accept `InputStream` as param insteed of filename.

It could be something like that

```
InputStream configFile = args.length > 0
  ? new FileInputStream(args[0])
  : ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.yml");
```

and read resource from that stream later on.